# Should acronyms be used as tags?

Tags: discussion, tag-management

My question was spurred by the following [t1dm](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/t1dm)? For the average person, this tag will probably be useless.

Should the name of the tag be more descriptive? If not, there are many medical terms that have obscure acronyms which wouldn't benefit many people and could lead to confusion, improper use of a tag, or not using a tag at all.

Also do we need [t1dm](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/t1dm) when [diabetes](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diabetes) exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Are abbreviations or full words preferred for tag names?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114385/are-abbreviations-or-full-words-preferred-for-tag-names)

Essentially, if possible in the 25 character limit, the term should be spelled out, and any acronyms can be set up as synonyms.